# OpenMP on outer loop: How to print output after inner loop?

Tags: c, printf, openmp

I have a program that defines a matrix *Pixel*, a function *iBlend* (which I can't see or change) that operates on two cells in *Pixel* returning a float, and actually just contains the following:

```
float RowResult[columns];
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   float sum = 0;
   RowResult[0] = 0;
   for (int j = 1; j < columns; j++) {
       RowResult[j] = iBlend(Pixel[i],Pixel[j],RowResult[j-1]);
       sum += RowResult[j];
   }
   printf("Row %d scored a total of: %f\n", i, sum);
   if (sum > 100) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) printf("%f,",RowResult[j]);
      printf("\n");
   }
}
```

This code goes through a matrix, a row at a time, doing some fancy-pants math with the indices i and j.

Naturally, this leads to gibberish when I try to run this with more than 1 thread because threads are calling printf on a first-come, first-serve basis.

I tried adding a simple `#pragma omp single` to the second part of the function (creating a block from the first printf until the second-to-last line), but I get the classic error about not being able to nest omp blocks:

```
> error: work-sharing region may not be closely nested inside of
> work-sharing, ‘critical’, ‘ordered’, ‘master’, explicit ‘task’ or
> ‘taskloop’ region
>    #pragma omp single 
>            ^~~
```

A few solutions came to mind. First was "just define a big enough matrix to hold all the answers and then loop over them at the end with one thread." But this way I actually run out of memory -- it turns out only a few rows really get printed, so doing it on the fly is totally essential. I also can't change the format of the output, although which row is printed in which order doesn't matter, as long as it's printed row-wise and the pixels are in order per row.

Another solution I thought about was "just flip the two loops and have the omp loop go through the pixels in the other direction, and then when that parallel loop is done I'm in single-threaded land again!" -- but turns out the rows need to have their pixels calculated in order because there's a carried dependency (iBlend needs the result of a previous computation).

At first I thought this was a simple problem, so maybe I'm just missing something obvious. I just want to exit "multithread" mode when I'm printing. Maybe something like "add this result to the stack of answers (treat adding to stack as 'atomic' with OpenMP?)" and then "if I'm the master thread, print everything on the stack so far in order"? But that'd be slow and a little tricky to implement. I'm sure there's an easier way. ...Right?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a critical region: `#pragma omp critical` with a block around the print out statements. However, the truly easy way to deal with this is just move the print-out statements outside of the parallel region. Right now, you're having threads access data (`RowResult[j]`) that may or may not be initialized.

Comment: Hi, thanks -- I also found adding #pragma omp ordered worked (but unnecessarily made everything print out in order -- critical is faster!). What do you mean about the RowResult[j] not being initialized? And how can I move things out of the parallel region?

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect with my previous `RowResult[j]` statement. Everything is OK in that regard. By moving things out of the parallel region, I *strongly* suggest that computation be done in parallel, and any IO (even to the console) be done outside of the parallel region.